# How to get a JFrame in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a simple app and I need to access `JFrame` created when initializing a program from different places where it's not always possible to access it directly (e.g. contentPane is empty so `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component)` won't work). Is there any other way to do this? For example, this is a class resposinble for initialization:

```
public final class Application{
     public static void start(){
         //Empty screen with menu
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Start");
                menuBar.add(menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
         });
     }
}
```

And I need to use it from some other places, e.g.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//initialize the panel
//push it to the content pane of Main frame
```

So, in order to share the main frame I tend to wrap it in a singleton class and then provide a static method. Maybe there is another way of doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in a static reference:

```
public final class Application{
     static JFrame mainFrame;                            //static attribute 
     public static void start(){
         //Empty screen with menu
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
                mainFrame = frame;                        //Storing in static attribute
                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Start");
                menuBar.add(menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
         });
     }
}
```

An call it as follows:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//initialize the panel
Application.mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

This is a ugly solution maybe you can review Design Patterns for a better solution:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/